Getting errors in my project screen : validation and Api using load data to screen and show the entered data in Recyclerview
API Using getting data in spinner view in the  screen, Enter the data in EditText view and   enter length and width automatically show the values with multiply symbol in size textview and bags and pieces values are calculated and shown in qty view and finally add all data in recylerview.
MaterialDetails Activity class:
public class MaterialDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements InterfacePassResponseBackToClassObj {

    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList<ItemDatum> itemData = new ArrayList<>();
    ResponsePojo responsePojo;
    CommonObj commonObj;
    EditText color, length, width, size, bags, pieces, qty, price;
    ArrayList<Mat_Pojo> datalist = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView Material;
    Button button;
    MaterialAdapter materialAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<String> itemlist = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_material_details);

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.item_names);
        color = findViewById(R.id.color);
        length = findViewById(R.id.length);
        width = findViewById(R.id.width);
        size = findViewById(R.id.size);
        bags = findViewById(R.id.bags);
        pieces = findViewById(R.id.pieces);
        qty = findViewById(R.id.qty);
        price = findViewById(R.id.price);
        button = findViewById(R.id.apply_button);
        Material = findViewById(R.id.txt_material);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_data);
        commonObj = new CommonObj(this, this, "testing");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Object selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem();


                String ItemName = selectedItem.toString();
                for (Mat_Pojo item : datalist) {
                    if (item.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(ItemName)) {
                        Toast.makeText(MaterialDetails.this, "Item already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                String Color = color.getText().toString();
                String Length = length.getText().toString();
                String Width = width.getText().toString();
                String Size = size.getText().toString();
                String Bags = bags.getText().toString();
                String Pieces = pieces.getText().toString();
                String Qty = qty.getText().toString();
                String Price = price.getText().toString();

                Mat_Pojo data = new Mat_Pojo(ItemName, Color, Length, Width, Size, Bags, Pieces, Qty, Price);

                datalist.add(data);

                materialAdapter = new MaterialAdapter(MaterialDetails.this, datalist);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MaterialDetails.this));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(materialAdapter);

                length.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (!length.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !width.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            size.setText(length + " x " + width);
                        } else {
                            size.setText("");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
                });

                width.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (!length.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !width.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            size.setText(length + " x " + width);
                        } else {
                            size.setText("");
                        }
                    }
                });

                bags.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        if (!bags.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !width.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            int quantityValue = Integer.parseInt(bags.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(pieces.getText().toString());
                            qty.setText(String.valueOf(quantityValue));
                        } else {
                            qty.setText("");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
                });

                pieces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        if (!bags.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !width.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            int quantityValue = Integer.parseInt(bags.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(pieces.getText().toString());
                            qty.setText(String.valueOf(quantityValue));
                        } else {
                            qty.setText("");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
                });


            }
        });

        callApiLoginList();

    }

    private void callApiLoginList() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        commonObj.CallApiRequestObj("api/example", "POST", map);
    }

    @Override
    public void apiCallBackOverRideMethodObj(Response<Object> response, JSONObject objResponse, String method, int position, String success) throws JSONException, IOException {
        if (response != null) {
            commonObj.HideLoad();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
            responsePojo = new Gson().fromJson(object.toString(), new TypeToken<ResponsePojo>() {}.getType());
            if (responsePojo.getItemData() != null) {
                itemlist.clear();
                for (ItemDatum item : responsePojo.getItemData()) {
                    itemlist.add(item.getItemName());
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MaterialDetails.this, R.layout.spinner_item, itemlist);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
}



I am  getting errors so confused about this above code.
